# Python - connect to S3 with profile only?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

When I SSH into my EC2 instance - I can use `aws s3 ls --profile myprofile` and can see data in S3 since at that point of time - I assumed `myprofile` which has access to specific buckets in S3. 
In that very moment - I do not provide any secret and access key (just `--profile myprofile`).

How to achieve the same using Python?
So far I've seen only by using Boto library but it ask for Secret/Access keys. Trying to avoid that but just use profile if possible (as it is possible by using aws cli).

Thanks.

Comment: aws cli stores your access key and secret key. You don't have to specify it since it is retrieved automatically when required

Comment: Does Python library support - automatic grabbing of passwords?

Comment: No but you can store the credentials as environment variables to keep them safe.

Comment: So how come AWS CLI can do it (just assume profile) but Python can not do it? What is so special about AWS CLI?

Comment: AWS CLI is an iterface built by AWS to do this. You can write a python program that will store and retrieve credentials from OS enviornment or a config file just like AWS does if you want. You will have to program this yourself though.

Comment: When you install aws cli on your system you have to configure it with your access key and secret key. It is just saving them and fetching them later

Comment: The AWS CLI is a Python program that also uses boto3. See linked answer for example of how to specify the profile with using boto3. The profile option will use credentials stored in the `~.aws/credentials` file.